# Problem setting up azure datafactory to azure devops git

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to hook up my Azure Data Factory to Azure Devops Git.   However when i select "Azure Devops Git" as repository type i get:

"Could not find a valid Visual Studio Online account"

I have made sure that my Devops is 
"This organization is backed by the  Azure Active Directory."

Have anybody seen this problem?

Comment: Do you able to login to your AzureDevOps account normally without trying from Azure?

Comment: Yes, it is operational, i have some other repos there.

Answer (score 3):

Also - if you just created your organization and connected the AAD - be sure and log out of all the browsers and log back in. I left the portal open in a browser and until I logged out I couldn't see a repo.

Comment: Aha, this is what was just getting me! I connected my directory but I had to log out of my azure portal and my visual studio browser login, restart my browser, then my repos started appearing once I logged in again

Answer (score 1):

I Know it is a very old thread. I faced the same problem today. Tried various things, but what worked for me is initializing one of the repositories in Azure DevOps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you are the admin of your Azure portal and Azure Devops account then do the following.

1. Go to organization Settings of Azure DevOps
2. Now Go to Azure Active Directory and then click on connect Directory and follow the process that pops up on the window.

After above steps move to Repository Settings in Azure Data Factory and after selecting Azure DevOps Git as repository type, check the box for Select different directory and choose default directory in the next option and there you go...